# How to create a custom database with 32k block size via DBCA silent mode?

Tags: oracle, configuration, installation, oracle-19c

I am trying to create an Oracle 19c single instance (warehouse) with dbca silent mode. The problem is, when I try the command below, it gets a warning: "Ora-0058: DB_BLOCK_SIZE must be 8192 to mount this database (not 32768)". Rest of the lines are full of errors.

The command:

```
dbca -silent -createDatabase -initparams db_block_size=32768 -templateName Data_Warehouse.dbc -gdbname ${ORACLE_SID} -sid  ${ORACLE_SID} -responseFile NO_VALUE  -characterSet WE8ISO8859P9  -sysPassword SysPassword1 -systemPassword SysPassword1    -databaseType DATA_WAREHOUSING  -memoryPercentage 40  -memoryMgmtType AUTO_SGA  -storageType FS -datafileDestination "${DATA_DIR}"  -redoLogFileSize 2048     -emConfiguration NONE   -ignorePreReqs
```

I assume this is because of the template I'm using. But I don't have any custom templates. Also I don't want to use GUI as I'm not going to have this option for certain reasons.

How can I fix the command so dbca won't fail?

Answer (score 0):

> dbca -silent ... -**gdbname** ${ORACLE_SID} -**sid**  ${ORACLE_SID} ...

Is this creating a *Pluggable* database inside an already-existing *Container* database?

If so, then the Block Size is defined by the Container database (which is a "real" Oracle database) and not the Pluggable database (which is, effectively, a Tablespace on steroids).

Comment: No, i'm not creating a pdb or cdb. It's old style database, standalone.

Comment: The Data Warehouse template appears to actively /prevent/ you from changing the block size.  https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/900595/cant-change-default-block-size-in-dbca

Answer (score 0):

Use the GUI (DBCA) in one of the test system and fill all the details you want to fill for the production environment. At the end there will be an option to export as a script or something similar.

The output will be a command which you can run on production and it will do the installation.

Otherwise use the Oracle documentation and find all the commands/options.